# Check if taxonomy is attached to at least one post in a post-type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

To check if at least one post in post-type `products` has the `led` term I usually do this:

```
$query = array('numberposts' => 1, 'post_type' => array('products'), 'television' => 'led');
$products = get_posts($query);

if ($products) {
echo 'At least one post has the term led';
} else {
echo 'No post with the term led';
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: That's the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK. The only problem I can see with this solution, is that you select all post data just to check if such post exists (and posts can be long).

So I would consider using custom query in this case (it gives you number of posts with this term assigned)

```
function my_count_posts_with_term($taxonomy, $term_slug, $post_type) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );

    $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->posts}
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships}
            ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}
            ON ({$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id)
        WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = %s
            AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = %s
            AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = %d;", $post_type, $taxonomy, $term->term_id));
    return $count;
}
```